# Load drawableLeft image for Button using databinding

Tags: android, data-binding

I have a Button that has an Icon and a text.

[image]

This is achieved with this code:

```
            <Button
                ...
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ghana"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ghana"
                android:text="@string/hint_ghana"

                 />
```

Databinding works with the text but not with the icon when I do this:

```
            <Button
                ...
                android:drawableLeft="@{countryOfResidence.thumbnail}"
                android:drawableStart="@{countryOfResidence.thumbnail}"
                android:text="@{countryOfResidence.countryName}"

                 />
```

This is the result:

[image]

I have looked for a solution to this but can't find any as most are focused on loading an image into and ImageView.

My Model class looks like this:

```
public class CountryOfResidence {

private String countryName;
private int thumbnail;


public CountryOfResidence(String countryName, int thumbnail) {
    this.setCountryName(countryName);
    this.setThumbnail(thumbnail);
}
....
```

In the `onCreate()` method of the calling Activity, am doing this

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActivitySignUpBinding signUpBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_sign_up);
    MyHandler myHandler = new MyHandler();
    signUpBinding.setMyHandler(myHandler);

    mViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.signUpViewFlipper);

    countryOfResidenceList = new ArrayList<>();
    countryOfResidenceList.add(new CountryOfResidence("Nigeria", R.drawable.nigeria));
    countryOfResidenceList.add(new CountryOfResidence("Ghana", R.drawable.ghana));
    countryOfResidenceList.add(new CountryOfResidence("Kenya", R.drawable.kenya));

    signUpBinding.setCountryOfResidence(countryOfResidenceList.get(1));
```

Finally, the data tag in my layout looks like this

```
<data>

  ...
    <variable
        name="countryOfResidence"
        type="orem_tech.com.teylur.model.CountryOfResidence"/>
</data>
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It appears that you are passing in a resource ID to the `android:drawableLeft` attribute instead of a `Drawable`. By default android data binding will automatically convert integers to `ColorDrawable` because it assumes that they are colors.

There are a few ways to solve this. The first is to add a method:

```
public Drawable loadDrawable(Context context, int resourceId) {
    return context.getDrawable(resourceId);
}
```

and then bind it like this:

```
android:drawableLeft="@{MyUtil.loadDrawable(countryOfResidence.thumbnail)}"
```

You could also make `thumbnail` a `Drawable` instead of an `int`:

```
public final ObservableField<Drawable> thumbnail = new ObservableField<Drawable>();
```

You could also create your own BindingAdapter to accept an int argument. Follow the example in `TextViewBindingAdapter`:

```
@BindingAdapter({"android:drawableLeft"})
public static void setDrawableLeft(TextView view, int resourceId) {
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(view.getContext(), resourceId);
    setIntrinsicBounds(drawable);
    Drawable[] drawables = view.getCompoundDrawables();
    view.setCompoundDrawables(drawable, drawables[1], drawables[2], drawables[3]);
}

private static void setIntrinsicBounds(Drawable drawable) {
    if (drawable != null) {
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
    }
}
```

If you do the above, you won't be able to use data binding to set an integer color as a drawable. If you want to separate it, you could use a different (app namespace) attribute. But you probably don't need to set color drawables as `drawableLeft` anyway.

Comment: this solution worked for me, only instead of `android:drawableLeft="@{MyUtil.loadDrawable(countryOfResidence.thumbnail)}"` i had to put `android:drawableLeft="@{MyUtil.loadDrawable(context, countryOfResidence.thumbnail)}"`

Answer (score 2):

create `BindingAdapter` to all TextViews like this

```
@BindingAdapter("setDrawableRight")
fun TextView.setDrawableRight(resourceId: Int) {
    val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, resourceId)
    setIntrinsicBounds(drawable)
    val drawables = compoundDrawables
    setCompoundDrawables(drawables[0], drawables[1], drawable, drawables[3])
}

private fun setIntrinsicBounds(drawable: Drawable?) {
    drawable?.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.intrinsicWidth, drawable.intrinsicHeight)
}
```

and use in this way

```
app:setDrawableRight="@{R.drawable.ic_check_24}"
```

Thanks to George Mount

Answer (score 1):

It is bit late answer but for future seekers 
If you can change your model

From

```
private int thumbnail;
```

to

```
private Drawable thumbnail;
```

Then you can pass drawable directly to layout instead of resource id

your model will become

```
public class CountryOfResidence {

private String countryName;
private Drawable thumbnail;


public CountryOfResidence(String countryName, Drawable thumbnail) {
    this.setCountryName(countryName);
    this.setThumbnail(thumbnail);
}
....
```

you can initialize your list like this

```
countryOfResidenceList = new ArrayList<>();
    countryOfResidenceList.add(new CountryOfResidence("Nigeria", ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.nigeria)));
```

and that is it send model to layout and load drawable normally like

```
<Button
                ...
                android:drawableLeft="@{countryOfResidence.thumbnail}"
                android:drawableStart="@{countryOfResidence.thumbnail}"
                android:text="@{countryOfResidence.countryName}"

                 />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have drawable represented as **Int** (DrawableRes) you can use this:

```
android:drawableStart="@{androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, config.icon)}"
```

Same can be done with color for example:

```
android:textColor="@{androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getColor(context, config.iconColor)}"
```

Context is automatically defined in this case.